# where is new_ssl?

Tags: ssl, erlang, rabbitmq, macports

From rabbitmq documents I know there is an `new_ssl` application.
I have installed erlang through macport command. after using command `"port content erlang|grep new_ssl"`, I can't find it.

In www.erlang.org, new_ssl document, it says `new_ssl` is an module not an application.
But reading `ssl.app`, it also doesn't contain `new_ssl` module?

Is it a ghost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new vs old ssl are two different implementations of SSL. Old ssl used libopenssl directly where as new ssl is build in erlang with only libcryto functions in C. As of the R15B release (dec 2011) of Erlang/OTP, the old_ssl implementation was entirerly dropped.